# SVN with Tortorise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to know something. Using tortoise is it possible to download the versions of just one ONE single file. I'm mean not all the repository, just all the versions of one single file.

Regards.

Comment: what do you mean by 'download'? Do you mean checkout? or update?  export?  You may not even need an svn client, if the svn repo is served up by apache you can grab it with a browser or wget.

Comment: what client are you using? how are you accessing svn? http/https? file:// svn+ssh?

Comment: I'm new in this, so I'm going to try to explain myself as crystal as possible. The project is located in http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/xtext-typesystem/trunk/. I wanna download all the version of just one simple file using tortoise.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way with TortosieSVN to download all revisions of a single file with a single action. You need to identify each revision where there was a change to the file, then export each revision in turn.

This is much better done through a scripting language and the command-line client, `svn.exe`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you recomind any another solution?

Comment: I think I already gave you another solution (to the question as stated - you haven't gotten into *why* you think you need to do this, and if you did, there may be a better solution - but as you've already decided on how you want to approach this, this is the recommendation) in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is very possible.

Right click the file -> SVN Update

It will update only that one file. Or one folder. Or as many selected files/folder combination you'd like.

---

If, in case, the project has not been checked-out yet, you can point the checkout address to the file itself, and it will download only that one file.